# With shapes inside a group, I can use method 'ShapeRange.Align' in Excel VBA but in Powerpoint VBA why does not it work?

Tags: excel, vba

In `Excel VBA` method 'Align' works normally

```
Sub testExcelVBA()
  With ActiveSheet.Shapes
    With .AddShape(msoShapeRectangle, 0, 0, 100, 100)
        .Name = "shp1"
        .Select
        .Fill.ForeColor.RGB = rgbRed
    End With
    
    With .AddShape(msoShapeOval, 300, 300, 50, 50)
        .Name = "shp2"
        .Select msoFalse
        .Fill.ForeColor.RGB = rgbRed
    End With
  End With

  ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange.Group
  
  ActiveSheet.Shapes.Range(Array("shp1", "shp2")).Select
  
  With ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange
    .Align msoAlignCenters, msoFalse
    .Align msoAlignMiddles, msoFalse
  End With

End Sub
```

But in `Powerpoint VBA`, it works normally with argument 'msoTrue' or 'msoCTrue'. But with 'msoFalse' the program raises runtime error below:

[The specified value is out of range.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YkftF.png)

The similar code as Excel VBA with Powerpoint here:

```
Sub testPowerpointVBA()
  With ActiveWindow.View.Slide.shapes
    With .AddShape(msoShapeRectangle, 0, 0, 100, 100)
        .Name = "shp1"
        .Select
        .Fill.ForeColor.RGB = rgbRed
    End With
    
    With .AddShape(msoShapeOval, 300, 300, 50, 50)
        .Name = "shp2"
        .Select msoFalse
        .Fill.ForeColor.RGB = rgbRed
    End With
  End With

  ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange.Group
  
  ActiveWindow.View.Slide.shapes.Range(Array("shp1", "shp2")).Select
  With ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange
    .Align msoAlignCenters, msoFalse
    .Align msoAlignMiddles, msoFalse
  End With

End Sub
```

All explaining would be appreciated.

Comment: Check the PowerPoint object model to make sure you have a correct reference to the mso stuff.

Comment: At second code, if 2 shapes are not in a group then it works normally. Or 2 shapes still be in a group but I change the second argument of method 'Align' to 'msoTrue' so it also works normally. I tried to detect problem many times before posting here. That my question is: How method 'Align' works with shapes in a group in Powerpoint VBA?

Comment: Finally I found the ways to fix it. At second codes, we change `With ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange`  into `With ActiveWindow.Selection.ChildShapeRange` then that codes work well like the first which in Excel VBA.